# Symfony - Replacement for Scope in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony

I read that the container scope concept has been deprecated in 2.8 and will be removed from 3.0.

> The "container scopes" concept explained in this article has been
>   deprecated in Symfony 2.8 and it will be removed in Symfony 3.0.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

What is the replacement for that? How can i have a singleton scoped service or a request scoped service? Is that possible? What is the default scope?

I'm sorry i use the deprecated word. But how do i approach this?

What is it replaced with? Can someone point me to any related docs?

**As i read more of Symfony, i realize i confuse the Scope of Spring with Symfony. That makes this question slightly irrelevant as there was/is nothing called a singleton scoped service. The service container lives only as long as the request. Please correct me if i'm wrong.**

[What is the lifespan of the service container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870385/symfony-what-is-the-lifespan-of-the-service-container)

Comment: The article you linked explain the `reason why scopes exist, and how they can cause problems. Keep reading to find out the common solutions.`

Comment: _The service container lives only as long as the request._ - Yup. That's how php works. When the script has finished its execution all objects that hold will be lost. No shared memory between requests. Global variables don't persist or are shared between two distinct php scripts.